# React Native Video

Tags: react-native

i'm trying to use 'react-native-video' in my application, i have used the following lines to get it:

```
npm install --save react-native-video
react-native link react-native-video (since my react native version is  0.59)
```

after doing so and using "Video" component from 'react-native-vide' i got an error like below:
[image]
what is the problem? what can i do? any ideas?

Comment: Looks like it's not linked.

Comment: @LeeBrindley i did run "react-native link react-native-video" to link the react-native-video library

Comment: Are you use Pods? If so, did you run pod install>?

Comment: @LeeBrindley im not using pod, i use npm and i did run npm install after seeing this error, also i have removed node_modules and then run npm install again, but nothing works.

Comment: With React Native the 2 (Pods, npm) are not exclusive. Try rebuild the application, and check the linking is correct. It's almost certainly a linking issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not link the library properly.
After having installed the library through `npm i --save react-native-video`, you'll need to run `react-native link react-native-video` in order to link it. This may or may not work - if it does not, you'll need to link manually according to the installation instructions of the library.

You might be using CocoaPods in which case you'll need to run these commands as well: `cd ios && pod install`

If you receive an error, you're most likely not using CocoaPods and this is the wrong approach.

Please note that you'll need to reinstall the app on the phone / simulator afterwards since you've changed the native dependencies. You'll also need to do this if you're using (ejected) Expo or anything alike. If you're using Expo with the managed workflow (= not ejected) you're not able to use libraries that depend on native linking.

Comment: i did what you mentioned in first paragraph, and it didn't work, i am using expo with managed workflow, so what to do then? i believe there is a Video component of expo so (silly question) if i use that is it going to work after i have published my app?

Comment: That's what I thought. You cannot link native dependencies while using Expo. So your only options would be to either detach / eject from Expo if you really want to use libraries that depend on native linking (which does have its drawbacks though if you like the managed workflow - see https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject/), or use libraries already included in Expo or libraries that don't require native linking. Your best bet would probably be to just use the Expo Video library, correct. You might need to run `expo install expo-av`: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/video/

Comment: thanks a lot, i user expo's video library and it works.